# SQL Alchemy what does persistently bound mean?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am new to SQL Alchemy and am trying to import a schema.

The [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/reflection.html) mention:

> If the MetaData is not persistently bound, also add the autoload_with
>   argument

What does persistently bound mean?

If I have previously written this:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
metadata = sa.MetaData()
metadata.bind = engine
```

Does that mean it's persistently bound?